# C++/C# Windows: Get USB power/bandwidth consumption

Tags: c#, c++, windows, usb

The usb hub properties contains 2 following tabs.

Power: http://take.ms/xUPJY

Bandwidth: http://take.ms/ta5Ri

How to get this data programmatically? WMI doesn't contains data about it.

Comment: What searches have you done? (BTW don't include links to picture on SO. Include the picture inline). Which WMI namespaces did you look at?